# One element's vertical alignment varies based on content of adjacent element

Tags: html, css

Here's what I am unable to recreate: [image]

[link to jsfiddle for reference](https://jsfiddle.net/childishgovindo/4y0y9ch8/)

Here's the issue I'm having, "BBC" appears to jump up/down based on whether sign in included in the next div block. I can't get the border to stay within the 40px or get the "sign in" or "BBC" text to center or the BBC to center. I spent a couple hours testing various items, I wasn't able to get it to work--It would be very much appreciated if you could explain the code and the behavior that is taking place (why the HTML is rendering the way it is). Why do the BBC and left border of Sign In overflow the 40px height?

```css
html, body, p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.top-nav-bar {
  height: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px firebrick solid;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.top-nav-logo-area {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 25px;
}
.logo {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 25px;
}
.top-nav-link-div {
  display: inline-block;
  border-left: 1px #cccccc solid;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!-- WITH CONTENT NEXT TO LOGO -->

<div class="container top-nav-bar">

  <div class="top-nav-logo-area">
    <span class="logo">B</span>
    <span class="logo">B</span>
    <span class="logo">C</span>
  </div>

  <div class="top-nav-link-div">
    hello
  </div>
</div>


<!--WITHOUT CONTENT NEXT TO LOGO -->

<div class="container top-nav-bar">

  <div class="top-nav-logo-area">
    <span class="logo">B</span>
    <span class="logo">B</span>
    <span class="logo">C</span>
  </div>

  <div class="top-nav-link-div">
    <!-- empty -->

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're dealing with `inline-block` elements. The problem is their default `vertical-align` value: `baseline`. Add `vertical-align: top` to `.top-nav-logo-area`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/36975280/3597276

Comment: @Michael_B that's a super helpful link! `vertical-align: top` definitely solves the problem of alignment, but  `vertical-align: middle` does not seem to respond. Could you provide some insight to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're dealing with `inline-block` elements.

The default value of the `vertical-align` property, which applies to inline-level elements, is `baseline`. This takes the logo container (`.top-nav-logo-area`) and aligns its baseline (or bottom margin edge, if there is no baseline),  with the baseline of the parent box (`.top-nav-bar`).

Except, you have constrained the height of the parent with `height: 40px` (the natural height is 46px).

This forces the logo box to overflow the bottom of the parent.

Whether or not the height of the parent is shortened, the `vertical-align` property should work on the logo container.

*From the spec:*

> ### [`vertical-align`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align)
>
> This property affects the vertical positioning inside a line box of
>   the boxes generated by an inline-level element.
>
> ***baseline***
>
> Align the baseline of the box with the baseline of the parent box. If
>   the box does not have a baseline, align the bottom margin edge with
>   the parent's baseline.
>
> ***middle***
>
> Align the vertical midpoint of the box with the baseline of the parent
>   box plus half the x-height of the parent.

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

html, body, p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.top-nav-bar {
    height: 40px;             /* height constrained; natural height 46px */
    border-bottom: 1px firebrick solid;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.top-nav-logo-area {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 25px;
    border: 1px dashed red;
    vertical-align: top;     /* other options include `baseline`, `bottom` and `middle` */
}

.logo {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.top-nav-link-div {
    display: inline-block;
    border-left: 1px #cccccc solid;
    height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!-- WITH CONTENT NEXT TO LOGO -->
<div class="container top-nav-bar">
    <div class="top-nav-logo-area">
        <span class="logo">B</span>
        <span class="logo">B</span>
        <span class="logo">C</span>
    </div>
    <div class="top-nav-link-div">
        hello
    </div>
</div>

<!--WITHOUT CONTENT NEXT TO LOGO -->
<div class="container top-nav-bar">
    <div class="top-nav-logo-area">
        <span class="logo">B</span>
        <span class="logo">B</span>
        <span class="logo">C</span>
    </div>
    <div class="top-nav-link-div"><!-- empty --></div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: How were you able to determine 46px as the natural size of the box?

Comment: In Chrome dev tools, unclick the `height: 40px` and check Computed tab.

Comment: Thank you! One final question: why does the computed height end up being 46px? The `.logo` class only has a `font-size` of 25px; even if default `line-height` is 120%, the box will only be 30px. This will explain why 'BBC' is baselining at 46px by default.

Comment: The mystery height is coming from the text div in the first row ("Hello"). If you remove the `height: 40px` from `.top-nav-link-div`, then remove the `height: 40px` from `.top-nav-bar`, the only spacing left is the `margin-bottom: 30px`. Remove that and all spacing is gone.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want to achieve:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cLkgLLbx/1/)

I used `float left` so the logo isn't affected by the text. I also made some enhancements you will like:

```css
html,
body,
p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.container {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.top-nav-bar {
    height: 40px;
    border-bottom: 1px firebrick solid;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.top-nav-logo-area {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 7px 7px 0 20px;
    float: left;
}

.logo {
    background-color: #222;
    color: white;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 22px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    margin: 0 0 0 3px;
    line-height: 26px;
    cursor: default;
}

.top-nav-link-div {
    display: inline-block;
    border-left: 1px #cccccc solid;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 0 7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container top-nav-bar">

  <div class="top-nav-logo-area">
    <span class="logo">B</span><span class="logo">B</span><span class="logo">C</span>
  </div>

  <div class="top-nav-link-div">
    hello
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That works! Could you please provide further commentary as to why you used `float` instead of `inline` (why is it a better choice?) and also why you need to use both 'line-height: 40px` and `height: 40px`.

Answer (score -1):

Nor sure what the issue is, but you can try add box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box; to your elements :)

Also try float:left; it might solve it.

Please add a jsfiddle too, is easy to solve the problem for you then.