# Span element with display: inline-flex has greater height than sibling span

Tags: html, css, height, flexbox

While playing with flex container I have noticed that both Chrome and Firefox render it with a height 1px greater than static siblings.

Here is the code:

```css
.container {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.main {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.flex-cont {
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="main flex-cont">
      This is the flex container, height is 20px
     </span>
  <span class="main">
      This is not the flex container, height is 19px
     </span>
</div>
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/pzoxfs90/

Does anybody know why is this and how to avoid it?

Answer (score 5):

Your `span` elements are, by default, inline-level elements.

The initial value of the [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) property, which applies to inline-level elements, is `baseline`. This allows browsers to provide a bit of space below  elements to accommodate [descenders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36975280/3597276).

When you apply `display: inline-flex` to one of the spans you establish a [***flex formatting context***](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers). In this case, the children are *blockified*, meaning that the behavior is more like a block-level element.

Hence, the `vertical-align` property no longer applies to span1, but it continues to apply to span2, which is why you still see the descender space.

From the spec (referring to the [anonymous box](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-items) which wraps the text and is the flex item):

> [**4. Flex Items**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-items)
>
> The `display` value of a flex item is blockified: if the specified
>   `display` of an in-flow child of an element generating a flex
>   container is an inline-level value, it computes to its block-level
>   equivalent.

The simplest solution is to make the parent a flex container, which keeps your child elements inline by default, and allows you to set flex properties on both.

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    background-color: yellow;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.main {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <span class="main">This is the flex container, height is 20px</span>
    <span class="main">This is not the flex container, height is 19px</span>
</div>
```

[**Revised Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pzoxfs90/3/)

More details:

- [Why is there a vertical scroll bar if parent and child have the same height?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36974514/3597276)
- [In CSS Flexbox, why are there no "justify-items" and "justify-self" properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an `display:inline;` issue, changing it to `display:inline-block;` fixes the height difference. Not sure how useful this is though...

```css
body {
  margin: 30px;
} 

.container {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.main {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display:inline-block;    
}

.flex-cont {
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <span class="main flex-cont">
  This is the flex container, height is 20px
 </span>
 <span class="main">
  This is not the flex container, height is 20px
 </span>
</div>
```