# Why is item being vertically centered when I add a display flex to it?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

To replicate bug:

1. Resize your browser width so that you can see the "ALDO" logo
2. Uncomment this 1 line of code

   ```
   .logobox {
        /* display:flex; */
    }
   ```
3. "ALDO" logo becomes vertically centered.
4. Why are the logo's being vertically centered when I add a display of flex? Shouldn't this only happen if I add a justify center or align center? What is causing this bug?

Comment: you can use SVG with a single shape & the same size to reproduce your issue .

Comment: I don't think doing that would replicate my issue as my logos are not the same height and width.

Comment: i meant the same size of the originals, else where is the point ?

Answer (score 2):

The "Aldo" logo is an image file. Generally speaking, whether it's an `img` or `svg` element, images are set to `display: inline` by default.

Inline level elements are set, also by default, to `vertical-align: baseline`. This setting raises the image slightly from the baseline (the line upon which text rests). This extra space is created to accommodate "descenders", which apply to text, not to images, but `display: inline` doesn't make that distinction.

When you switch from `display: inline` to `display: flex`, the images are automatically set to `display: flex`, which renders them as block-level elements. Such elements are not set to `vertical-align: baseline`.

In your code, this results in the images shifting downward into the descender space.

More details here:

- [Mystery white space underneath image tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31445364/3597276)
- [Why is my textarea higher up than its neighbor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32414736/3597276)
- [Span element with display: inline-flex has greater height than sibling span](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38352014/3597276)

Comment: | "When you switch from display: inline to display: flex, the images are automatically set to display: flex, which renders them as block-level elements." Does this mean that if I change the display: flex to display: block, it will also "center" the ALDO logo? Because when I changed the display:flex to display: block, the ALDO logo did not center.

Comment: You cannot change the `display` property on flex items. It's controlled by the flex container and will ignore author-defined rules.