# Remove gap between divs that have no margin and padding

Tags: html, css

I have two divs, one of class `mini-date-holder` and one of class `mini-event-holder`.

Despite the fact that both have no margin and padding, they are being rendered with a gap between them and I cannot seem to figure out why.

Anybody know why they have a gap between them and how I can get rid of it?

Ideally, the three dots should be just below the number.

I know I can use something like `transformY`, but I'd rather figure out why they're being rendered so far apart to begin with.

Refer to [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zxos4eos/2) or the code below.

```css
.mini_date {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Roboto", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.mini-event {
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 2px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-right: 3px;
}
.mini-event-holder {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.mini-date-holder {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mini_date">
  <div class="mini-date-holder">10</div>
  <div class="mini-event-holder">
    <div class="mini-event"></div>
    <div class="mini-event"></div>
    <div class="mini-event"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The only adjustment you need to make is to add `vertical-align: top` to `.mini-event-holder` => [Revised Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zxos4eos/8/) | [Explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36975280/3597276)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.mini_date{
 flex: 1;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: "Roboto", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
 font-weight: 400;
}
.mini-event{
 width: 4px;
 height: 4px;
 background:red;
 border-radius: 2px;
 float: left;
  margin-left: 1px;
  margin-right: 1px;
}

.mini-event-holder{
 margin: 0 auto;
 height: 4px;
 display: inline-block;
 margin:0px;
 padding: 0px;

}
.mini-date-holder{
 margin: 0px;
    line-height: 1em;
 padding: 0px;
}

.mini_date{
     line-height: 0; 
}
```

```html
 <div class="mini_date">
      <div class="mini-date-holder">10</div>
      <div class="mini-event-holder"> 
       <div class="mini-event"></div>
       <div class="mini-event"></div>
       <div class="mini-event"></div>
      </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the `line-height` property.
try setting the line height on the 2 divs to 0.

Comment: So this removes the gap, but moves the text up as well. Is there any way to do it without having the text move? Or will I have to use transformY on the dots after all?

Comment: That is where you use padding or margin to move your divs into position.