# Why inline-flex element with clearfix has a weird white space?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a weird behaviour of an `inline-flex` element when applying a clearfix to it. When I set a clearfix to an element which has an `inline-flex` display property the strange white space appears before it:

[image: inline-flex]

But when the `inline-block` is used the behaviour is different:

[image: inline-block]

I don't understand why `inline-flex` has a different behaviour than `inline-block`.. and why it has that weird space.

```css
.a,
.b {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.a {
  text-align: center;
}
.b {
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.cf:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b cf"></div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/infous/jeca65my/)

Comment: Why would you do that in the first place? Clear fix is a horrible hack to deal with hacking layouts using floats … and flexbox is a replacement for hacking layouts using floats.

Comment: @Quentin, heh, good question! I found it not in my code..

Comment: @Quentin: The kind of people who use the clearfix hack with abandon are the kind of people who lack a fundamental understanding of what it does in the first place, and often even of floats in general.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### `display: inline-flex`

When you use `display: inline-flex`, you establish a flex container.

An initial setting of a flex container is `flex-direction: row`.

This means that all in-flow child elements of the container (including in-flow pseudo-elements) will line up in a row. The `display` value of these children (`table`, in this case) is overridden/ignored, in accordance with the rules of a  [*flex formatting  context*](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers).

Your flex container has two flex items (the pseudo-elements) in one line:

```css
.a,
.b {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.a {
  text-align: center;
}
.b {
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
  content: "x";
  display: table;
}
.cf:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b cf"></div>
</div>
```

---

### `display: inline-block`

When you use `display: inline-block`, you establish a [*block formatting context*](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#block-formatting).

The `display` property of child elements is respected.

Your pseudo-elements with `display: table` are block elements which, by default, occupy the full available width. Hence, the pseudos are creating two rows:

```css
.a,
.b {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.a {
  text-align: center;
}
.b {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
  content: "x";
  display: table;
}
.cf:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b cf"></div>
</div>
```

---

### `vertical-align: baseline`

Because both versions of your code use inline-level `display` values, this calls into play the `vertical-align` property, who's initial value is `baseline`.

The white space you are seeing below `div.b` when set to `display: inline-flex` is due to baseline alignment.

The white space you are seeing below `div.b` when set to `display: inline-block` is due to baseline alignment *in combination with the effects of two block element children*.

Here is a more detailed explanation:: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36975280/3597276

---

### The `clear` property

```
.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

Your clearfix method is not the source of any of the white space. In fact, it's having no effect on your layout and can be safely removed.

You use the `clear` property only when dealing with floats.

*From the spec:*

> [**9.5.2 Controlling flow next to floats: the `clear`
>   property**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#flow-control)
>
> This property indicates which sides of an element's box(es) may not be
>   adjacent to an earlier floating box.

Not only are there no floated elements in your layout, but if there were, the `float` and `clear` properties are nonetheless ignored in a flex formatting context.

> [**3. Flex Containers: the `flex` and `inline-flex` display
>   values**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers)
>
> - `float` and `clear` do not create floating or clearance of flex item, and do not take it out-of-flow.

Answer (score 12):

Try set a `vertical-align: top` to your `inline-flex | inline-block` element to fix this offset.

https://jsfiddle.net/jeca65my/2/

Thank's to @NenadVracar on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38872761/unknown-offset-inline-flex-element-clearfix#comment65107478_38872761)

Comment: should be `vertical-align: top;`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to imagine your page as a `flow`. Every element of your page is in the flow (DOM). You are using the position property to change the position in the flow.

> block

A block element will **Always** start a new line. (ie: div)

> inline-block

Inline blocks elements are blocks like `div` but with `inline` properties in it. (ie: span)

> inline-flex

This is used the same way as `inline-block` in the flow. It makes a container that is `inline` but with the `flex` layout.

For your example, an interesting thing to do in order to focus on the difference between `inline-block` and `inline-flex` is to add text in your child div. You'll see that the comportment of your child div will once again change because it has text in it. [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/jeca65my/1/)

**EDIT :** I found a sentence on SO that resumes well the situation. thank's to [@BoltClock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock) on [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27418104/difference-between-displayinline-flex-and-displayflex) :

> display: inline-flex does not make flex items display inline. It makes the flex container display inline.