# Unknown offset. (inline-flex element + clearfix)

Tags: css, flexbox, inline, pseudo-element, clearfix

Unknown offset. In latest Chrome, FF, IE

Explain please, what the **top** offset (1em) ?

[image]

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5q08Lqnf/3/)

```css
#a {
  border:1px solid blue;
}


#b {
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
  display: -webkit-inline-flex;
  display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
  display: inline-flex; /* inline-table too */
  border:1px solid red;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}


#b:after { /* bootstrap clearfix */
  display:table;
  content:'';
}
```

```html
<div id="a"><div id="b"></div></div>
```

Similar question: [Why inline-flex element with clearfix has a weird white space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38872653/why-inline-flex-element-with-clearfix-has-a-weird-white-space)

Comment: `vertical-align` fixes it https://jsfiddle.net/5q08Lqnf/4/ also adding some content  https://jsfiddle.net/5q08Lqnf/5/ but not sure why.

Comment: @NenadVracar can you please write an answer for my question? Your `vertical-align` solution fixes the problem. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38872653/3597276