# align-items: center distorts height of parent

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to build, something like a carousel, that you can slide using a scrollbar. In each of the slides, there's a single line of text that should be both horizontally and vertically centered. 
Setting `align-items: center` changes height of the parent `div`.

```css
.carousel {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #dbdbdb;
  overflow-y: visible;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.carousel .slide {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 15px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  text-align-last: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="slide">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
  <div class="slide">quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="slide">consectetur, adipisci</div>
</div>
```

Comment out the `align-items` and it fits alright. How should I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not `align-items: center`. That's all good.

The problem is that your flex container is an inline-level box (`display: inline-flex`), which activates the `vertical-align: baseline` default setting.

Since your middle item has two lines of text, the box adjusts its baseline to line-up with its siblings. (Notice how all boxes line up when they each have a single line of text.)

Just override the default with `vertical-align: bottom`.

```
.carousel .slide {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```css
.carousel {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #dbdbdb;
  overflow-y: visible;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.carousel .slide {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 15px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  text-align-last: center;
  vertical-align: bottom;  /* NEW */
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="slide">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
  <div class="slide">quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="slide">consectetur, adipisci</div>
</div>
```

Also note:

- the problem doesn't exist when you remove `align-items: center` because the default value is `stretch`, which allows the text to align at the baseline (i.e., first line) across boxes regardless of the number of lines ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nwd414yy/))
- `flex-start` would also work ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nwd414yy/1/))
- `flex-end` would not ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nwd414yy/2/))

More details about `vertical-align: baseline`:

- [Why is there a vertical scroll bar if parent and child have the same height?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36974514/3597276)

Comment: Thank you! +1 for the explanation!

Comment: Also thanks for the post with extra details! That solved another of my problems. :D