# Vertical centering fails when Flexbox is removed

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm not sure why is this happening. When I remove:

```css
.nav-username {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

the elements align horizontally, however, the image and text stop being aligned vertically because I've removed the `display: flex` and `align-items: center`.

```js
$('.dropdown').on('click', function() {
  $('.navigation-ul li:not(:first-child)').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

a {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

html {
  font-size: 16px;
}

body {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.navigation {
  background-color: #171717;
}

.navigation-ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.navigation-ul>li:not(.dropdown) {
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: white;
  background-color: #151719;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.navigation-ul li:nth-last-child(2) {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.nav-username {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.profile-picture {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

@media all and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .navigation-ul {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .navigation-ul>li {
    flex: 1 1 100%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .navigation-ul li:first-child {
    display: block;
  }
  .navigation-ul li {
    display: none;
  }
  .navigation-ul li.active {
    display: block;
  }
  .navigation-ul .dropdown {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .home-container {
    columns: 2;
  }
  .dropdown {
    padding: 7px 0 7px 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .specific-image-flexbox {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .home-container {
    columns: 1;
  }
  .category-container-element {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class='navigation'>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="navigation-ul">
      <li class='dropdown'>Dropdown</li>
      <li><a href="">Images</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Categories</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Upload</a></li>
      <li>
        <a class='nav-username' href=''>
          <img class='profile-picture' src=''> Username
        </a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add property `justify-content:center;` as well. So it will be centered align vertically and horizontally.

So, you need to update

```
.nav-username {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

to

```
.nav-username {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Interestingly enough, this is the the solution that fixed my problem.

Comment: This might be the solution that fixes your overall problem, but it's not a solution to the problem you described in the question, which was about vertical centering with and without flexbox.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an issue with putting a display type flex onto an anchor tag. I've placed the flex class onto the list item and it appears to work fine:

```js
$('.dropdown').on('click', function() {
  $('.navigation-ul li:not(:first-child)').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

a {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

html {
  font-size: 16px;
}

body {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.navigation {
  background-color: #171717;
}

.navigation-ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.navigation-ul>li:not(.dropdown) {
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: white;
  background-color: #151719;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.navigation-ul li:nth-last-child(2) {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.nav-username {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.profile-picture {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

@media all and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .navigation-ul {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .navigation-ul>li {
    flex: 1 1 100%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .navigation-ul li:first-child {
    display: block;
  }
  .navigation-ul li {
    display: none;
  }
  .navigation-ul li.active {
    display: block;
  }
  .navigation-ul .dropdown {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .home-container {
    columns: 2;
  }
  .dropdown {
    padding: 7px 0 7px 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .specific-image-flexbox {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .home-container {
    columns: 1;
  }
  .category-container-element {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class='navigation'>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="navigation-ul">
      <li class='dropdown'>Dropdown</li>
      <li><a href="">Images</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Categories</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Upload</a></li>
      <li class='nav-username'>
        <a href=''><img class='profile-picture' src=''> Username</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: The problem is that now the username is not vertically aligned with the image. I've used flexbox on the anchor to fix that problem.

Comment: You can add the style vertical-align: middle; to your profile-picture class on the img tag. I've updated the snippet with this and it seems to have solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS code:

```
.nav-username {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

... is being applied to an anchor element:

```
<a class='nav-username' href=''>
    <img class='profile-picture' src=''>
    Username
</a>
```

Let's start with what happens when **flex is removed**.

- An anchor element is, by default, an inline-level element. This means that it takes up only the space of its content. With inline-level elements, the [`width` property](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#inline-width) and the [`height` property](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#inline-non-replaced), do not apply.
- Then consider that the [`vertical-align`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36974514/3597276) property applies to inline-level elements (and table-cell elements). Its default value is `baseline`, which means that inline-level elements start out with [baseline alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36974514/3597276).
- So, without *flex layout*, an anchor element falls back to *block layout*, and the above settings are in place. To vertically center the text in this case, try `vertical-align: middle`.

  ```
  /* .nav-username {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
     } */

  .nav-username > * {
      vertical-align: middle;
  }
  ```

[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ga5dfn4v/)

When **flex is active**, here's how it plays out:

- A flex container converts its child elements into flex items, which are block-level elements, [by definition](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-items). This conversion ignores the element type. So elements that are inline-level or block-level in *block layout*, are *block-level* in flex layout.
- This means that the `vertical-align` property is ignored by flex items and, together with the explanation above, explains why the vertical centering is working when flex is in place, but not when flex is removed.

Comment: The problem with this is that the image and username are not aligned which each other the way they are when using flexbox on their parent element.

Comment: Aligned vertically? They are. I tested it (on Chrome).